# Tomcat 8.5 ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when calling getRealPath

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

In some very rare cases we get this error when calling `getRealPath` in `Tomcat 8.5.50`

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 244
    at java.io.ExpiringCache.cleanup(ExpiringCache.java:120)
    at java.io.ExpiringCache.get(ExpiringCache.java:76)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:406)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractFileResourceSet.file(AbstractFileResourceSet.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.getResource(DirResourceSet.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResource(CachedResource.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getRealPath(StandardContext.java:4384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getRealPath(ApplicationContext.java:387)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getRealPath(ApplicationContextFacade.java:339)
```

We did not face this issue when we where using `Tomcat 7`, and I think it may be was OK at `Tomcat-8.5.15`.

After the exception the server stops responseing and we need to restart it.

We are using struts2.5 as MVC.

Comment: Which JRE version are you using?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz it is `jdk1.8.0_251`

Comment: Looks to me like a JRE bug.